# Django Prepopulate HTML MultieChoice Field

Tags: html, django, selected

What's the best way to prepopulate a multiple choice select field. In my view, I'm adding the context the values for the field.

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(UserProfileUpdateView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['mystates']=user.states
```

output

```
Alaska, Arizona, Alabama,
```

Hmtl page

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_states">Add State 2:</label> <select name="states" id="id_states"  multiple="multiple">
    {% include "accounts/snippets/states_drop_down_options.html" %}
    </select>
</div>
```

state_drop_down_options.htmlm

```
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>    
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>    
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>    
  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>    
  <option value="CA">California</option>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24403075/4107823

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each option you can check if that option is in the `mystates` variable:

```
  <option value="AL" {% if 'Alabama' in mystates %}selected{% endif%}>Alabama</option>    
  <option value="AK" {% if 'Alaska' in mystates %}selected{% endif%}>Alaska</option>    
  <option value="AZ" {% if 'Arizona' in mystates %}selected{% endif%}>Arizona</option>    
  <option value="AR" {% if 'Arkansas' in mystates %}selected{% endif%}>Arkansas</option>    
  <option value="CA" {% if 'California' in mystates %}selected{% endif%}>California</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your project, you can have it the way that you think better for your purpose.

**1st**: 
[Django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) or [Django.forms.MultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield)

**2nd**:[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50110893/5644965) of @Nazkter is a good one,

**3rd**:

*html*
(I add a `states` attribute to `select` containing the value of `{{ states }}`)

```
<select name="states" states="{{ states }}" id="id_states"  multiple="multiple">
    {% include "accounts/snippets/states_drop_down_options.html" %}
</select>
```

*javascript*

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#id_states option')  , function(elm){
    var states = document.querySelector('#id_states').getAttribute("states").replace(/\s/g,'').split(",");
    if(states.indexOf(elm.innerText) > -1){
        elm.selected = true;
    }
});
```