# Django timezone and dateTime format display

Tags: django

How can I give the user switch:

1. date time format
2. timezone

both to display different `dateTime` as the user determined.

I want to enable this options in admin Django or UI.
Not manually settings page.

Comment: Reading your question, is not exactly clear what you need. Please try to rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to create model (UserFormats) for storing this data from users. Two fields - `datetime_format` and `timezone`. These fields will be ChoiceField - example of implementation you can found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24404791/5450939 . Keys are numbers and values are formats what you want (you can import from pytz

```
import pytz
pytz.all_timezones
```

).
This model will be ForeignKey to your User model.

Also, add Boolean field like a `is_user_datetime_format_enabled` and a `is_user_timezone_format_enabled`.
It will allow you to switch options in the Django admin for every user.

Then you can check in your code or template:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
if user.userformats.is_user_datetime_format_enabled:
     today.strftime(user.userformats.datetime_format) 
else:
    today.strftime("%d/%m/%y"). # some default formatting

 ...
```

With timezone the same situation.