# Connecting django multiple choice field with textinputs

Tags: python, django

In django models, I used models.MultipleChoiceField but i want that those variables in the set of choices to be linked to a textinput which will be saved into the django admin. So the user selects the choice then keys in a textbox and saves for that choice is that possible to implement?

Comment: No, you didn't use models.MultipleChoiceField, because there is no such thing. If you want help, you need to show you actually did by posting your code, and explaining what you want the outcome to be.

Comment: Hey Daniel I see you have a pretty experienced reputation, if you dont mind me asking, Im an intern at a company through a school program. So could you advice me on dealing with alot of forms with django. Like should I prioritise learning more about data structures and what not as these forms are related in different ways. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403075/django-choicefield)

If you want to "those variables in the set of choices to be linked to a textinput", it will be use `forms.ChoiceField` in `forms.Form`.

it will be nicely if you posting your code, the better we may know what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help bud.